How to determine lambda for graphical lasso?
I am trying to figure out how to determine lambda for a graphical lasso.
I have found that someone had the exact same question that me 9 years ago. I was wondering if anything exists in R to determine lambda in context of graphical lasso?
How to perform Cross-Validation for glasso to select lambda in R

I did my master's thesis on this, so I might be able to help, but what is it you need? The titular question can be answered with: By writing a cross-validation loop. There is nothing special needed for glasso, except that you should use the maximum likelihood estimate of $S=\hat{\boldsymbol{\Sigma}}$, otherwise a single sample covariance matrix is undefined (for LOOCV). The body of the question, however, seems to suggest you're not yet sure about whether you need glasso. Can you clarify the research question?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

At this stage, it is very exploratory, I am just trying to understand the approach of network analyses on a dataset I have already analyzed with a simple lasso regression. I would like to set lamda correctly with glasso to see if a node (my DV in the simple lasso) is related to the same variables (my IVs in the lasso regression). Then I just want to try to interpret the rest of the relation for the other nodes, to see if it makes sense and if I could use this approach on different dataset in the future. Do you have published your master thesis somewhere? Online repository?

Hi @Simon, I will add an answer later, but here is a link: A comparison of methods for the construction of conditional independence networks. In short, since the goal is mostly exploration at this point, have you considered other techniques? rags2ridges allows you to estimate a graph using a proper ridge penalty and uses a local false discovery rate (by default) to decide on the number of edges. It has a built-in function for cross-validation.

See the linked part of the vignette.

The graphical LASSO (glasso) uses an $\ell_1$-norm penalized log-likelihood to obtain an estimate of $$\mathbf{\Theta} = \mathbf{\Sigma}^{-1},$$
the inverse variance-covariance matrix, or precision matrix.
The log-likelihood, as described in the original paper by Friedman, Hastie & Tibshirani (2008),$^1$ is equal to
$$\log \left( \det \left( \mathbf{\Theta} \right) \right) - \mathrm{trace}(\mathbf{S \Theta}) - \lambda ||\mathbf{\Theta}||_1$$
where $\mathbf{S}$ is an empirical estimate of $\mathbf{\Sigma}$ and $||\cdot||_1$ is the $\ell_1$-norm.
Several ways to determine the optimal value of $\lambda$ have been described in literature:

Cross-validation;
Extended Bayesian Information Criterion (EBIC);$^2$
Stability Approach to Regularization Selection (StARS).$^3$

In addition, while not really providing an optimal value, the matrix condition number is a simple and effective tool to determine a lower bound for $\lambda$ by assessing the invertibility of $\mathbf{S}$. I also describe these methods to varying extends in my master's thesis, which is available online.$^4$
Choosing $\lambda$ through $k$-fold cross-validation
The easiest to implement (and perhaps also the easiest choice to defend) is by using a cross-validation loop. The idea is to estimate $\mathbf{\Theta}$ on the train set, and evaluate using an empirical estimate $\mathbf{S}$ of the test set. Other than that, it's mostly just trying to reproduce the log-likelihood formula above in R code.
Here is a quick implementation:
require("glasso")

kcv_glasso <- function(X, lambda, k = 10){
  fold <- sample(1:k, nrow(X), replace = TRUE)
  ll <- numeric(k)
  for(i in 1:k){
    train <- which(fold != i)
    test  <- which(fold == i)
    X_train     <- scale(X[train, ], center = TRUE, scale = FALSE)
    S_train     <- t(X_train) %*% X_train / length(train)
    Theta_train <- glasso(S_train, lambda)$wi
    logdetTheta <- determinant(Theta_train, logarithm = TRUE)[[1]][1]
    X_test <- scale(X[test, , drop = FALSE], 
                    center = attr(X_train, "scaled:center"), scale = FALSE)
    S_test <- t(X_test) %*% X_test / length(test)
    traceSTheta <- sum(diag(S_test %*% Theta_train))
    # The (penalized) log-likelihood:
    ll[i] <- logdetTheta - traceSTheta - lambda * norm(Theta_train, type = "1")
  }
  return(ll)
}

Let's try it out on two examples, one where we should not need any shrinkage ($n \gg p$) and one where we do ($n < p$).
Example: Invertible without shrinkage ($n \gg p$)
set.seed(2024)
X <- as.matrix(iris[, -5])
k <- 10
lambdas <- exp(seq(-20, 1, l = 100))
ll <- matrix(ncol = k, nrow = length(lambdas))
for(i in 1:length(lambdas)){
  ll[i, ] <- kcv_glasso(X = X, lambda = lambdas[i], k = k)
}
plot(rowMeans(ll, na.rm = TRUE) ~ lambdas,
     type = "l", bty = "n", log = "x", axes = FALSE,
     xlab = bquote(lambda), ylab = "log-likelihood", lwd = 3)
points(lambdas[which.max(rowMeans(ll, na.rm = TRUE))], 
       max(rowMeans(ll, na.rm = TRUE)), pch = 16, col = 2, cex = 1.5)
require("sfsmisc")
eaxis(1)
eaxis(2)


Example: Ill-defined without shrinkage ($n < p$)
set.seed(2024)
n <- 50
p <- 100
X <- matrix(rnorm(n * p), nrow = n, ncol = p)
k <- 10
lambdas <- exp(seq(-4, 4, l = 100))
ll <- matrix(ncol = k, nrow = length(lambdas))
for(i in 1:length(lambdas)){
  ll[i, ] <- kcv_glasso(X = X, lambda = lambdas[i], k = k)
}
plot(rowMeans(ll, na.rm = TRUE) ~ lambdas,
     type = "l", bty = "n", log = "x", axes = FALSE,
     xlab = bquote(lambda), ylab = "log-likelihood", lwd = 3)
points(lambdas[which.max(rowMeans(ll, na.rm = TRUE))], 
       max(rowMeans(ll, na.rm = TRUE)), pch = 16, col = 2, cex = 1.5)
eaxis(1, n.axp = 1)
eaxis(2)


In the second example, we get a clear optimum of $\lambda$, whereas in the first example, any value, no matter how low, still results in a similar log-likelihood. You can also see there is considerable variability from splitting the data, so for a precise estimate of $\lambda$ it would be better to use multiple runs of $k$-fold cross-validation.
Some notes:

Since you mentioned the study is exploratory in nature, and there is no apparent strong preference for glasso, consider the proper ridge penalized inverse covariance estimation implemented in the rags2ridges package. It  uses a local false discovery rate (by default) to decide on the number of edges and has a built-in function for cross-validation. It also has the usual advantages over LASSO, including the ability to separate the estimation and variable-selection process, and less sensitivity to colinearity.
If you have a small sample size, and want to use LOOCV, it is important to use the maximum likelihood estimate of $\mathbf{S}$ and not apply Bessel's correction.



Jerome Friedman, Trevor Hastie, Robert Tibshirani, Sparse inverse covariance estimation with the graphical lasso, Biostatistics, Volume 9, Issue 3, July 2008, Pages 432–441, https://doi.org/10.1093/biostatistics/kxm045
Foygel, R. & Drton, M. (2010). Extended Bayesian information criteria for Gaussian graphical models. Curran Associates Inc.
Liu, H., Roeder, K., & Wasserman, L. (2010). Stability Approach to Regularization Selection (StARS) for High Dimensional Graphical Models. Advances in neural information processing systems, 24(2), 1432–1440.
Rodenburg, F.J. (2017). A comparison of methods for the construction of conditional independence networks Leiden University Mathematical Institute (Thesis repository)


I discover a new R function here: eaxis. I have always been doing this manually (like here) or with a custom function. In the second graph the axis does however look less nice. R does this often and plots logarithmic graphs with levels at 1,2,5 because of the xaxp graphical parameter. With eaxis(1, n.axp = 1) it looks better in my opinion.

Thanks for providing such a complete answer, I'll take a close look. A colleague of mine told me about EBICglasso as well. Is that also a function that may help to pick the optimal lambda?

@Simon, You're welcome! I'm not familiar with that function, but there's also the package huge, which allows glasso estimation using EBIC. I included some example code of that here.
